# Did Artifactory change its repository naming conventions? If so, when and why?

Tags: maven, naming-conventions, artifactory

In the past, Artifactory had a set of pre-defined local respositories, as described here:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Local+Repositories

- libs-release-local
- libs-snapshot-local
- ext-release-local
- ext-snapshot-local
- plugins-release-local
- plugins-snapshot-local

Now, it seems that JFrog is recommending a new naming convention for Artifactory:
https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-structuring-naming-artifactory-repositories/

They now recommend the scheme

```
<team>-<tech>-<matury>-<locator>
```

Does this mean that these repositories should now be called something like

- myteam-mvn-release-local

etc.?

When did Artifactory make this change, and why?

Comment: The white-paper is to set a convention. You can name your repository as you wish. This is to help in the case where you have a lot of repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention described in the whitepaper is a recommendation aimed at helping you with organizing your repositories, especially you have many of them. You can follow any convention which suites your needs.
Historically, the pre-defined repositories were created when Artifactory was a Maven repository. They are suitable for Maven repositories, with the classic separation between releases, snapshots and plugins. With Artifactory becoming a universal repository manager, supporting various technologies such as NuGet, NPM, Docker and GoLang, the pre-defined repositories did not suite all package types (relevant for the commercial and community editions).
In newer versions of Artifactory you can use the "Quick Setup" in order to create a set of default repositories per package type, including local, remote and virtual repositories.